# Error from inside the Android tools: check the console

Tags: android, windows, processing

I'm using windows 7, processing 2.2.1.The code i.e.

```
void setup(){
  size(300,300);
}
void draw(){
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(mouseX,mouseY,40,40);
}
```

works fine in java mode but gives the below described error in Android mode. Please help me on this, I'm new to processing.
This is the error i am getting:

```
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
Installed at C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: sketch_140704a
Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for sketch_140704a...
Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for sketch_140704a...
Library dependencies:
No Libraries

------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
input: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\classes
input: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar
input: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\libs\processing-core.jar
Pre-Dexing C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\libs\processing-core.jar -> processing-core-772a27754f9c5e0f1acc71d5ba1d4960.jar
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Temp\android1550940716866401979sketch\bin\classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] 1 error; aborting

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Simmu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1

Total time: 33 seconds
```

Comment: your console gives a FileNotFoundException on "annotations.jar". fix your library directory on your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tools folder is not updated. You can execute the following command to update it.

```
android.bat update sdk -u -a -t 1,2
```

The above android command is in the your /tools/ folder. Or else you could use the SDK Manager from your sdk folder and update/install the tools->Android sdk tools , Android sdk platform tools, also update/install android support library from extras

This should solve it